# Woocommerce single product tabs creating space

Tags: wordpress

I recently moved the tabs from the single-product up to the summary row, on the single product - when loading the page applies `display: none;` to the first tab, so content cant be shown. This wasnt the problem before. I copied the whole content from the tabs.php file to my content-single-product.php file. Alongside that, it creates huge space below it. What could cause these problems?

You can see the problem here: http://feropa.dk/produkt/aliquam-lobortis/

Answer (score 0):

Your site doesn't show any reference to your question.

[image]

Comment: Ohh i see - i'll turn it off.

Comment: It has been turned off. Please check again.